# How to disable worldspawn in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On our SMP server we set worldspawn on accident but even if players go in beds and reconnect at the worldspawn how do we remove the worldspawn?

Comment: As per [this meta post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6950/when-should-we-edit-game-names-out-of-question-titles-and-why), game titles are appropriate in tites, given certain conditions and formats.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Are you talking about `/setworldspawn`? You're saying that your players always spawn at worldspawn when they reconnect? No sort of vanilla spawn has any bearing on the position of a player after a reconnect, which leads me to believe you are using Plugins

Answer (score 1):

What I do is make sure you unload your server then run [NBTExplorer](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1262665-nbtexplorer-nbt-editor-for-windows-and-mac) (a free program that allows you to edit NBT data files) and open your `level.dat` file located at `%appdata%/.minecraft/saves/<yourworldfolder>/`with it. In SMP you would need to locate your world data folder (it varies depending on how you install it).

Then go to the key for `SpawnX`, `SpawnY`, `SpawnZ` and delete them. That will remove the set spawn.

Either way, even with a set world spawn point beds should override that provided they sleep in the bed long enough for the screen to fade completely.

One thing that may be important to know if you work with redstone a lot or other automation/farms. As is rather common knowledge to seasoned players, around your initial starting point, known as world spawn, there are a number of 'chunks' which regardless of where players are will always remain loaded and active (which are different concepts). When you use `/setworldspawn` you actually redesignate which chunks are to be kept loaded. When you delete, per my instructions, and reload the world, you will reset them to their initial location (when you first created the world). If you have automation and farms that rely on the loaded chunks, you should move them as well.

You will need to save your changes in NBTExplorer and then reload your world.

Answer (score -1):

I take it that originally, players were to spawn at 0,0. Simply do `/spawnpoint 0,64,0` Change 64 to whatever the `y` coordinate is at 0,0. Simple as that.

Comment: The difference is that initial spawn isn't exactly 0,0. It's a random location within a larger region (I think centered around 0,0). When you use /setworldspawn you overwrite the behavior and it spawns at an exact block coord.

Comment: @ydobonebi The bit about `/setworldspawn` is not entirely true. It sets the spawn region for the world, not a precise block. Unless your players are in Adventure mode, then it's a precise block. Not sure why, but that's the behavior.

Comment: @StuartWagner Read teh wiki very carefully.  not in adventure mode, the game ONLY moves them up the y axis to spawn them in a valid spot, but the x,z are maintained. In adventure mode the y is also maintained. So slightly mistaken, but mostly accurate all the same.

Comment: @ydobonebi My personal experience and testing has led me to believe otherwise. Try it out.

Comment: @StuartWagner I have, many times in fact. But just for fun, I loaded up the latest snapshot and tested.... it's spawning me withing +/- 8 blocks of the setblock along both the x and z axis. So that has been changed/fixed since the versions I run my server at (1.7.x) and the wiki also hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: @StuartWagner Which, still btw isn't like the natural spawn point which will spawn you more like +/- 3 chunks of it

Comment: @ydobonebi Interesting. I run my stuff at 1.8 and it behaves just like a natural spawn point. Also, I don't think the natural ones spawn within 3 chunks, but rather a 20x20 block area centered on the spawn block. The wiki says that area is reduced to 10x10 in multiplayer, but I believe that is incorrect. I can easily reproduce the 20x20 behavior on a server within a few tries.

Comment: @StuartWagner Sorry, I meant +/-1 chunk out from the setspawn chunk (which +/- 20 would make that correct but just shy of full chunk more. And my servers which run 1.8 I've not used /setworldspawn so I don't know when it got changed then. But I setworld spawn in the snapshot and killed myself 100 times... always withing +/- 8 blocks (really, +/- 7 as I set 0 0 as spawn, both |x| and |z| where always < 7.5,) (NOTE: 0 ~ 0 is really 0.5 ~ 0.5)

Comment: @ydobonebi Maybe the wiki has it backward then. 10x10 in singleplayer and 20x20 in multiplayer. That could be. Anyway, this has gone off topic :P