# Why are my players respawning at the world spawn rather than their beds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I set the home, and set the bed to wake up. But when I die, I start automatically on the world spawn area.

Can you tell me how to set that all players in the server when they die, revive on their bed position?

Minecraft Server 1.19.2

Comment: Question is already asked here, might help you -> https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/230297/295645

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per MaxAuMax's comment.